# What is C1 operator in genetic algorithms?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I came across this term while reading an academic paper describing a genetic algorithm. I'm not sure what it actually refers to as it is not explained clearly in the paper.

What is clear about C1 operator: 
It is one of the crossover operators used in a genetic algorithm. There are other operators such as two-point crossover, uniform crossover, cycle crossover.

I wish to know the procedure that the C1 operator performs and how it affects the crossover results.

Hope someone can explain it or point to some useful references.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the paper?

Answer (score 1):

C1 operator crossover is another name to the [One-Point Crossover](https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp/blob/master/src/GeneticSharp.Domain/Crossovers/OnePointCrossover.cs).

> A single crossover point on both parents is selected.  All data beyond
>   that point in either is swapped between the two parents.